# How to get this UI in flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I have been trying to generate a sort of Podium in leaderboards page, the idea is that the number one on the LeaderBoaards will have a circleAvatar with a crown on top, the other two should be a little bit down the first. One on the left, the other on the right, both with a slightly smaller CircleAvatar.

I have done it in a Row. And this is what it looks like

[image: What it looks like]

But this is what I want it to look like.

(edited in Photoshop)

[image: What I am looking for]

I don't want to hardcode any numbers, like sizes of Containers or anything of the sort. I have tried different options, with Align, Spacer, using Stack, but so far I always find some problem to get to the final result. I wonder what is the best approach here to what I want to accomplish. Is there maybe another Widget that I am not considering for this task?

I made the #2 and #3 places smaller by using Transform.scale on the CustomWidget.

PODIUM AVATAR WIDGET CODE.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class PodiumAvatar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String profileImage;
  final int rank;

  const PodiumAvatar(
      {required this.profileImage, required this.rank, super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 150,
        width: 110,
        child: Stack(children: [
          const Positioned(
            top: 25,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
              radius: 55,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                foregroundImage: AssetImage(
                  'assets/images/profile_1.jpg',
                ),
                radius: 50,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
              left: 42,
              bottom: 10,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
                radius: 12,
                child: Text(rank.toString()),
              )),
          if (rank == 1)
            Positioned(
                left: 38,
                top: -3,
                child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/crown1.svg', height: 32))
        ]));
  }
}
```

PODIUM WIDGET (This is where I want to arrange the 3 items)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:trivia_app/widgets/podium_avatar.dart';

class Podium extends StatelessWidget {
  final String profileImage;
  final int rank1;

  const Podium({required this.profileImage, required this.rank1, super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end, //add this line
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Transform.scale(
              scale: 0.65,
              child: PodiumAvatar(profileImage: profileImage, rank: rank1)),
          PodiumAvatar(profileImage: profileImage, rank: rank1),
          Transform.scale(
              scale: 0.65,
              child: PodiumAvatar(profileImage: profileImage, rank: rank1)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please share your code? did you try crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center which will push the row components in horizontal center?

Comment: Hello !, I edited my original post to share the code.   The questions I obtained worked with Circle Avatar, but not with my widgets. Because the widget is a little bit more complicated than just a Circle Avatar, I wanted to keep the logic, and used Transform.scale, and with Transform.scale the CrossAxisAlignment.end or other CrossAxisAlignment doesn't fix the issue. I didn't want to create another widget just for the smaller version, but it seems that is what I will need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Row needs crossAxisAlignment:

```
Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end, //add this line
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const [
            CircleAvatar(radius: 50,),
            CircleAvatar(radius: 75,),
            CircleAvatar(radius: 50,),
          ],
        ),
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Upvoted your comment, for the help but it didn't solve my particular issue. I left some comments above with the explanation. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

I think this solves your problem a screenshot from dart pad is attached

```
Container(
    padding:EdgeInsets.only(top:15,bottom:5),
    color:Colors.redAccent,
    child:Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end, //add this line
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: const [
        CircleAvatar(radius: 40,),
        SizedBox(width:30),
        Padding(
          padding:EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10),
        child: CircleAvatar(radius: 75,),
        ),
         SizedBox(width:30),
        CircleAvatar(radius: 40,),
      ],
    )
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Your code worked for me with Circle Avatar, in fact I tried that before with my widgets but it didn't work in that place, so I didn't want to mention that to see if I was doing wrong. The thing is that with my particular widgets (that two of them are scaled down), it doesn't work, it probably considers it still large for the purposes of aligning it to the bottom. thanks for the help anyways, I upvoted your answer, even if it didn't solved my particular problem